# Making a dynamic timecard for a work schedule in excel

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Maybe I'm asking a pretty basic question, but I've searched here (and on other sites) for an answer and I couldn't find it.

I'm making a work schedule for my workplace on Google Sheets, analogous to the example posted as an image down here, that includes an automatic time card for every worker (that is, a formula answering the question "which days had [WORKER] worked?").

I managed to make one, with the filter formula

```
=FILTER(A2:A16;{or(COUNTIF(B2:D2;$L$1);COUNTIF(F2:H2;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B3:D3;$L$1);COUNTIF(F3:H3;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B4:D4;$L$1);COUNTIF(F4:H4;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B5:D5;$L$1);COUNTIF(F5:H5;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B6:D6;$L$1);COUNTIF(F6:H6;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B7:D7;$L$1);COUNTIF(F7:H7;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B8:D8;$L$1);COUNTIF(F8:H8;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B9:D9;$L$1);COUNTIF(F9:H9;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B10:D10;$L$1);COUNTIF(F10:H10;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B11:D11;$L$1);COUNTIF(F11:H11;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B12:D12;$L$1);COUNTIF(F12:H12;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B13:D13;$L$1);COUNTIF(F13:H13;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B14:D14;$L$1);COUNTIF(F14:H14;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B15:D15;$L$1);COUNTIF(F15:H15;$L$1));or(COUNTIF(B16:D16;$L$1);COUNTIF(F16:H16;$L$1))}=TRUE)
```

that is the day column `A2:A16` filtered with a manual array column that check if every row `B:D` (representing an AM shift) OR every row `F:H` (PM shift) contains the worker's name `$L$1`.

This is not an optimal solution, because I have to write the array manually, in a very time-consuming and not flexible way (to add another column/another worker to the workshifts means that I'll have to correct every single row).

Is there another **better** way to use FILTER? So far I've been trying to use MATCH or HLOOKUP, but I'm a rookie and not so familiar with excel arrays.

[image: Work schedule example]

Comment: what is the output you want there ? just yes and no answer, or the names of the workshifts ? also, what info does Column B have ? workshift 1pm ?

Comment: This is a very long formula, I think its better if you can provide a link to a sample spreadsheet with some sample data where users to try to get your desired output.

Comment: @nabais: Column B was workshift 1am as you correctly guessed, I wasn't aware that the screenshot had cut out that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post this formula in your `K2` cell:

```
=query(
  {{A2:A\B2:D};{A2:A\F2:H}}; 
  "select Col1 where Col2 = '"&L1&"' or Col3 = '"&L1&"' or Col4 = '"&L1&"'"
)
```

It will work dynamically with your workers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. It's strange though that FILTER doesn't allow the possibility to do so